# Angular 2 unit testing - @ViewChild is undefined

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-template, ng2-bootstrap

I am writing an Angular 2 unit test. I have a `@ViewChild` subcomponent that I need to recognize after the component initializes. In this case it's a `Timepicker` component from the ng2-bootstrap library, though the specifics shouldn't matter. After I `detectChanges()` the subcomponent instance is still undefined.

Pseudo-code:

```js
@Component({
    template: `
        <form>
            <timepicker
                #timepickerChild
                [(ngModel)]="myDate">
            </timepicker>
        </form>
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('timepickerChild') timepickerChild: TimepickerComponent;
    public myDate = new Date();
}
    
// Spec
describe('Example Test', () => {
    let exampleComponent: ExampleComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModel({
            // ... whatever needs to be configured
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    });

    it('should recognize a timepicker'. async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const timepickerChild: Timepicker = fixture.componentInstance.timepickerChild;
        console.log('timepickerChild', timepickerChild)
    }));
});
```

The pseudo-code works as expected until you reach the console log. The `timepickerChild` is undefined. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same problem.

Comment: I have a vague feeling like most of the upvoters have a different problem. Make sure that your child component is not hidden by any `*ngIf="false"` directive. Also, after setting the rendering condition to `true`, do a `fixture.detectChanges()` which will (re-)create the previously undefined child component.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think it should work. Maybe you forgot to import some module in your configuration. Here is the complete code for test:

```ts
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ExampleComponent } from './test.component';
import { TimepickerModule, TimepickerComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

describe('Example Test', () => {
  let exampleComponent: ExampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, TimepickerModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [
        ExampleComponent
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
  });

  it('should recognize a timepicker', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const timepickerChild: TimepickerComponent = fixture.componentInstance.timepickerChild;
    console.log('timepickerChild', timepickerChild);
    expect(timepickerChild).toBeDefined();
  }));
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hhc3i0KECTs83JTeswHY?p=preview)**

Comment: If I want to test main component without including actual children, then is there any way to mock them out?

Comment: @Eugene Can you provide some example in stackblitz?

Comment: But `@ViewChild('timepickerChild') timepickerChild: TimepickerComponent;` should be private field.

Comment: Just a note, that null in jasmine is defined and returns true in this comparison. You should do not.toBeNull() instead.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure your child component does not have a *ngIf that is evaluating to false. If so, it will result in the child component as being undefined.

Comment: thank you very much, man. I resolved an issue with ur answer.

Answer (score 6):

In most cases just add it to declaration and you are good to go.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed
            .configureTestingModule({
                imports: [],
                declarations: [TimepickerComponent],
                providers: [],
            })
            .compileComponents()
```

Comment: Not a good solution in my opinion. If you declare components in your tests, you have a hard dependency to them. Meaning, if they (for some reason) stop working, your test will fail as well. You should rather go for mocking components (like for example here: https://medium.com/@cnunciato/a-simple-mock-component-for-angular-2-d79bd58a7b31)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test the main component with a *stub* child component, you need to add a provider to the stub child component; as explained in the article [Angular Unit Testing @ViewChild](https://indepth.dev/angular-unit-testing-viewchild/).

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ChildComponent,
      useClass: ChildStubComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class ChildStubComponent {
  updateTimeStamp() {}
}
```

Note the *providers* metadata, to use the class *ChildStubComponent* when *ChildComponent* is required.

You can then create your parent component normally, its child will be created with the type *ChildStubComponent*.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have `ViewChild` inside and outside of `ngIf`s, try the following.

**First** things first, **mock your child components**, for example with `[ng-mocks][1]`

```
import { MockComponent } from 'ng-mocks';
    
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [ExampleComponent, ...MockComponent(TimepickerComponent)],
                imports: [],
                providers: []
            }).compileComponents;
    
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
    
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
```

**If your ViewChild IS NOT inside an `ngIf`**, set the `static` property of the `ViewChild` to true. This way you have access to it at `ngOnInit`.

```
<form>
    <timepicker
         #timepickerChild
         [(ngModel)]="myDate">
    </timepicker>
</form>
@ViewChild('timepickerChild', { static: true }) timepickerChild: TimepickerComponent;
```

and in your test:

```
it('should recognize a timepicker', () => {
    console.log('timepickerChild', component.timepickerChild);
    expect(timepickerChild).toBeDefined();
});
```

**If your ViewChild IS inside an `ngIf`**, set the `static` property of the `ViewChild` to false (or just don't set it, default is false).

```
<form>
     <div *ngIf="condition">
        <timepicker
             #timepickerChild
             [(ngModel)]="myDate">
        </timepicker>
     </div>
</form>
@ViewChild('timepickerChild', { static: false}) timepickerChild: TimepickerComponent;
```

and in your test:

```
it('should recognize a timepicker', () => {
    component.condition = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    console.log('timepickerChild', component.timepickerChild);
    expect(timepickerChild).toBeDefined();
});
```

If you have a method inside the child component that you need to check if it was called, spy on it and then you can access it:

```
it('should recognize a timepicker', () => {
     component.condition = true;
     fixture.detectChanges();

     const spy = spyOn(component.timepickerChild, 'childMethod');

     console.log('timepickerChild', component.timepickerChild);
     expect(timepickerChild).toBeDefined();
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: static is what made it work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Even after following everything from the accepted answer, you are getting undefined instance of child component then kindly check if that component is visible.

In my case, there was `*ngIf` applied on the control that's why instance of child was undefined then I removed and checked and it worked for me

Comment: Yes, this [has already been said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894245/542251)

Answer (score -1):

For an alternative way of doing this refer this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966565/11797105

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30976668)