# Angular : How to Get @ViewChild reference in unit test fixture or mock it

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Under my component , i ve this variable which take reference for the html widget element (which i got from a 3rd library):

```
<dx-data-grid id="myWidget" #myWidget>
   ...
</dx-data-grid>
```

So in my ts file i call it this way :

```
  @ViewChild('myWidget') datatableWidget: DxDataGridComponent;
```

And in some method , i using it this way

```
myMethod(){
  this.datatableWidget.instance.myWidgetMethod();
}
```

Now in my test file , i want to test my method :  `myMethod()`

and as i m calling some private methode of my widget component , i got

```
 Cannot read property 'myWidgetMethod' of undefined
```

How may i get reference of **@ViewChild** from my fixture , or how may **i mock it or event spyOn It ??**

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: in order to reference an element from template as `@ViewChild('myWidget')` the element must be declared as a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) `<dx-data-grid id="myWidget">` should be `<dx-data-grid #myWidget>`

Comment: @ysf  it s done like you say , but how to use '@ViewChild' in spec files

Comment: it should work as it is. if it's not working, there must be a different problem. for that please provide more details about your test.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515877/4399281

Comment: @firasKoubaa can u share your spec, component & html file. I hope you are doing `fixture.detectChanges()`.  The error says that `this.datatableWidget.instance` is undefined. Also, I think you can directly access as `this.datatableWidget.myWidgetMethod()` as well.

Comment: Can you post your test file? It might be related to where you placed the fixture. Inside beforeEach or fakeAsync or something similar. Also, have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984483/why-does-testing-with-template-driven-return-undefined-value?noredirect=1#comment107893628_60984483