# Why does testing with template driven return undefined value?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, angular9

I'm trying to test a simple form using template-driven forms in Angular 9. I insert values into the inputs and click on a submit button, which sends the values to a service. The code works, but the test fails because the values always remain undefined.

I've created a demo of the problem to show here (my actual code would be too complex):

**app.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(f)">

      <input type="text" ngModel name="field1">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field2" name="field2">

      <input type="submit" value="submit">

      <br>field1: {{ f.value.field1 }}
      <br>submitedText: {{ submitedText }}
      <br>field2: {{ field2 }}

    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public submitedText: string;
  public field2: string;

  public submit(form: NgForm) {
    this.submitedText = form.value.field1;
  }
}
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('shoud to submit the text', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
    }).createComponent(AppComponent)

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const field1 = fixture.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input[name="field1"]');
    const field2 = fixture.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input[name="field2"]');
    const button = fixture.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

    field1.value = 'test 1';
    field2.value = 'test 2';
    field1.dispatchEvent(newEvent('input'));
    field2.dispatchEvent(newEvent('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    button.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.submitedText).toBe('test 1');
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.field2).toBe('test 2');
  });
});
export function newEvent(eventName: string, bubbles = false, cancelable = false) {
  const evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');  // MUST be 'CustomEvent'
  evt.initCustomEvent(eventName, bubbles, cancelable, null);
  return evt;
}
```

The result is:

```
Failures
AppComponent > shoud to submit the text
Expected undefined to be 'test 1'.
Expected undefined to be 'test 2'.
```

Could someone help me to make the inputs are correctly filled out by the test? Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe that you should dispatch `new Event('change')` instead?

Comment: The docs (https://angular.io/guide/testing) says "new Event ('input')", but I've also tested it with "new Event ('change')" and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Should `fixture.elementRef.nativeElement` be `fixture.nativeElement.hostElement` instead? Maybe you don't need the last `.hostElement` though.

Comment: I replaced "fixture.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(...)" with "fixture.nativeElement.hostElement.querySelector(...)", and gave the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined"

Comment: Try to remove the last .hostElement. Meaning `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(...)`

Comment: Now with this change it showed the same error mentioned in the question "Expected undefined to be 'test n'"

Comment: I just noticed that they are doing a `dispatchEvent(newEvent('input'));` in the link you provided. No space between new and Event! Does that help? I am not super familiar with testing, so I am sorry that I cannot be of more help :P

Comment: You're right! Unfortunately that didn't change the result, but "new Event" was wrong. I will correct in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, although I don't understand exactly why, since the documentation doesn't explain it.

There are different ways to correct the test.

In the example I created, it is necessary to include the test code inside a fakeAsync, and call the fixture.detectChanges() and tick() functions, respectively:

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('shoud to submit the text', fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
    }).createComponent(AppComponent)

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    // rest of the code ...
}));
```

I need to mention that my original code creates the component inside a beforeEach (without async), and that makes a difference. If you create the component inside a beforeEach without async, you must use fakeAsync in it, and you CANNOT call fixture.detectChanges() inside this beforeEach (that was what broke my original code). However, if your beforeEach has async, the use of fakeAsync is unnecessary, and using async or fakeAsync in your test (it) is optional.

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
    }).createComponent(AppComponent)

    fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it('shoud to submit the text', () => {
// rest of the code ...
```