# How to access the @ContentChildren in the spec file?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I am testing a component that has a query list of `@ContentChildren`. In my component these are accessible in the 'AfterContentInit` life cycle hook. But, when i intend to access the same in my spec file, my query list return me with an empty arrays.

I am trying to test the component **without creating any mock component** as it is done in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479704/angular-2-unit-testing-component-mocking-contentchildren). I have tried the solution provided in the link below but that didn't work for me.

[Angular 2 unit testing - @ViewChild is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724179/angular-2-unit-testing-viewchild-is-undefined)

**In my Component:**

```
    @ContentChildren(GetTemplateDirective) public templates: QueryList<GetTemplateDirective<AccordionTemplate>>;
```

**In the component's spec file:**

```
    it('should show the custom icon when the external template is passed', async(function () {
       accordionFixture.detectChanges();
       accordionComponent.ngAfterContentInit();
       console.log(accordionComponent.templates);
       expect(component.templates.toArray().length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query using debug element :

```
 const debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
 debugEl.query(By.directive(AccordionTemplate));
```